# How to Use Jets.js?

Tags: javascript

Jets File : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jets/0.14.0/jets.min.js

Html File :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="assets/jets.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    var jets = new Jets({
    searchTag: '#jetsSearch',
    contentTag: '#jetsContent'
    });
    </script>
    <input type="search" id="jetsSearch">
       <div id="jetsContent">
       <div>Barry Williamson</div>
       <div>Francis Reeves</div>
       <div>…</div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to get this result
[Jets.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE36p.png)

Search field for several words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're HTML is out of order. It should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jets/0.14.0/jets.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="search" id="jetsSearch">
    <div id="jetsContent">
        <div>Barry Williamson</div>
        <div>Francis Reeves</div>
        <div>…</div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var jets = new Jets({
          searchTag: '#jetsSearch',
          contentTag: '#jetsContent'
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thenk You, And How To Make Like This : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE36p.png

Comment: @IconoFiana You would use materialized tags, like so: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Material-Design-Tags-Input-Plugin-with-jQuery-Materialize-Tags/

Comment: Yes, And autocomplete

Comment: @IconoFiana look at the 'Typeahead' example in the link. There is autocomplete if you include the 'Typeahead'

Comment: does not work
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jets/0.14.0/jets.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="materialtags" />
    </body>
</html>

Comment: @IconoFiana ask another question, on how to add autocomplete with Jets.